# Build Firebase google signin in Django

Tags: python, django, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am looking to integrate firebase auth google sign in with Django. But I am not getting a clear picture of how can I achieve it. As Pyrebase has an attribute `sign_in_with_email_and_password` but not any for Google SignIn. How will view and template be designed?